# Javascript CreateElement in loop go back to previous looped value when button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, createelement

I'm working on a project that's a quiz like form. You get multiple questions and answers and you can click on any answer to create a personal result. I've already asked a question about this project because I didn't really know how to loop correctly and I fixed that problem, tho it's still not going great. Right now I'm creating a previous button and it kinda works, but not great.

My code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="question"></div>
    <div id="answer"></div>
    <button onclick="NextQuestion()" id="nextbtn">Next</button>
    <button onclick="PrevQuestion()" id="prevbtn">Previous</button>
    <div id="finalLink"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    class QuizPart{
        constructor(questionDescription, chosenAnswer, prefix){
            this.questionDescription = questionDescription;
            this.chosenAnswer = chosenAnswer;
            this.prefix = prefix;
        }
    }
    
    class ChosenAnswer{
        constructor(id, name){
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    let Quiz = [
        new QuizPart('Whats your size?', [
            new ChosenAnswer('6595', '41'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6598', '42'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6601', '43'),
        ], 'bd_shoe_size_ids='),

        new QuizPart('What color would you like?', [
            new ChosenAnswer('6053', 'Red'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6044', 'Blue'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6056', 'Yellow'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6048', 'Green'),
        ], 'color_ids='),

        new QuizPart('What brand would you like?', [
            new ChosenAnswer('5805', 'Adidas'),
            new ChosenAnswer('5866', 'Nike'),
            new ChosenAnswer('5875', 'Puma'),
        ], 'manufacturer_ids='),
    ]
    // console.log(Quiz);

    let url = [];

    let questionNumber = 0;
    let button = document.getElementById('answer');
    let questionName = document.getElementById('question');
    let nextbtn = document.getElementById('nextbtn');
    let prevbtn = document.getElementById('prevbtn')
    let resultbtn = document.getElementById('FLink');

    function NextQuestion() {
        let oldAnswerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_anwser');

        // Deletes old question when the next question is clicked
        for (let answerButton of oldAnswerButton) {
            answerButton.style.display = 'none';
        }

        let question = Quiz[questionNumber];

        // Displays answers of the questions
        for (let y = 0; y < question.chosenAnswer.length; y++) {
            let item = question.chosenAnswer[y];
            // Display answer buttons
            let btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.value = item.id;
            btn.className = "filter_anwser";
            btn.textContent = item.name;
            button.appendChild(btn);
        }
        // Check if your at the last question so the next button will stop being displayed.
        if (Quiz.length - 1 === questionNumber) {
            nextbtn.style.display = 'none';
            resultbtn.style.display = 'grid';
        }

        // Displays Question
        questionName.textContent = question.questionDescription;
        questionName.id = "questionID";

        // adds 1 to question to see a different question
        questionNumber++;
    }

    function PrevQuestion(){
        questionNumber--;
        let oldAnswerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_anwser');

        // Deletes old question when the next question is clicked
        for (let answerButton of oldAnswerButton) {
            answerButton.style.display = 'none';
        }

        let question = Quiz[questionNumber];

        // Displays answers of the questions
        for (let y = 0; y < question.chosenAnswer.length; y++) {
            let item = question.chosenAnswer[y];
            // Display answer buttons
            let btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.value = item.id;
            btn.className = "filter_anwser";
            btn.textContent = item.name;
            button.appendChild(btn);
        }
        //Check if your at the last question so the next button will stop being displayed.
        if (Quiz.length === questionNumber) {
            prevbtn.style.display = 'none';
            resultbtn.style.display = 'grid';
        }

        // Displays Question
        questionName.textContent = question.questionDescription;
        questionName.id = "questionID";
    }
```

Now as you can see I create a new element when I press the previous button (also seen in the next image): [image]

I'm trying not to create an entire new set of elements, but going back to the previous set. I tried doing it with a simple if statement like:

```
let i = 0;
if (i < question.chosenAnswer[y]){
    y--;
}
```

This is just something I tried but didn 't work. Can anybody help me do this?

Save the information:

```
    function getLink(url) {
        let tmp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
            // Check if question is from the same quiz part and adds a , between chosen answers and add the right prefix at the beginning
            if (url[i].length > 0){
                tmp.push("" + Quiz[i].prefix + url[i].join(","))
            }
        }
        /// If answers are from different quiz parts add a & between answers.
        console.log(url, questionNumber);
        return "" + tmp.join("&");
    };

    button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        const tgt = e.target;

        // clear the url array if there's nothing clicked
        if (url.length < questionNumber) {
            url.push([]);
        }

        let quizUrl = url[questionNumber - 1];

        // Check if a button is clicked. Changes color and adds value to the url array.
        if (quizUrl.indexOf(tgt.value) === -1) {
            quizUrl.push(tgt.value);
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        // Check if a button is clicked again. If clicked again changes color back and deletes value in the url array.
        } else {
            quizUrl.splice(quizUrl.indexOf(tgt.value), 1);
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
        console.log(getLink(url));
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retrieve the previously created buttons to show(*) them.

For instance you can retrieve them using their `id` which is put in their `value` attribute:

```js
for (let y = 0; y < question.chosenAnswer.length; y++) {
    let item = question.chosenAnswer[y];
    // retrieve the button by it's value="id" attribute
    let btn = document.querySelector('button[value="' + item.id + '"]');
    btn.style.display = 'grid';
}
```

(*) Note that when you say "Deletes questions" you actually are just hiding them, not deleting (i.e. removing from document).

Comment: It works! The only thing that's kinda weard is that whenever I press previous and add another value, it adds the value to a question even further back (so when i'm at color and click red it adds the right value to the size array). Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: It's a totally different question. You should accept my answer and post this as a new question with relevant code, instead of editing this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use element.remove() instead of element.style.display ="none"

Why?
element.remove() - will remove the DOM element altogether.
element.style.display ="none" - Will only hide it for the end user. But it will still be there on the DOM tree.

Js Fiddle for solution below:

Fixed a few thing in you code as well. Added comment lines in the places where I fixed things

1. Next button now disappears on the last question
2. Previous button now disappears on the first question

Edit:

Edited the code snippet with few logical changes.
Now the answers are maintained in the array as expected.
Although the buttons dont retain colour. This can be handeled in the previous and next button click functions in the same way which you have done the getLinks method.

```js
class QuizPart{
        constructor(questionDescription, chosenAnswer, prefix){
            this.questionDescription = questionDescription;
            this.chosenAnswer = chosenAnswer;
            this.prefix = prefix;
        }
    }
    
    class ChosenAnswer{
        constructor(id, name){
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    let Quiz = [
        new QuizPart('Whats your size?', [
            new ChosenAnswer('6595', '41'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6598', '42'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6601', '43'),
        ], 'bd_shoe_size_ids='),

        new QuizPart('What color would you like?', [
            new ChosenAnswer('6053', 'Red'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6044', 'Blue'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6056', 'Yellow'),
            new ChosenAnswer('6048', 'Green'),
        ], 'color_ids='),

        new QuizPart('What brand would you like?', [
            new ChosenAnswer('5805', 'Adidas'),
            new ChosenAnswer('5866', 'Nike'),
            new ChosenAnswer('5875', 'Puma'),
        ], 'manufacturer_ids='),
    ]
    //console.log(Quiz);

    let url = [];
    
            //FIX - INIT VALUE UPDATED TO -1
    let questionNumber = -1;
    let button = document.getElementById('answer');
    let questionName = document.getElementById('question');
    let nextbtn = document.getElementById('nextbtn');
    let prevbtn = document.getElementById('prevbtn')
    let resultbtn = document.getElementById('finalLink');

    function NextQuestion() {
            //FIX - PUSHED THIS LINE UP HERE TO HAVE SYNCED LOGIC 
            // adds 1 to question to see a different question
        questionNumber++;


        let oldAnswerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_anwser');

        // Deletes old question when the next question is clicked
        for (let answerButton of oldAnswerButton) {
           //CORRECTION DONE HERE
           answerButton.remove();
        }

        let question = Quiz[questionNumber];

        // Displays answers of the questions
        for (let y = 0; y < question.chosenAnswer.length; y++) {
            let item = question.chosenAnswer[y];
            // Display answer buttons
            let btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.value = item.id;
            btn.className = "filter_anwser";
            btn.textContent = item.name;
            button.appendChild(btn);
        }
        //FIX -FOR NEXT BUTTON AND PREVIOUS BUTTON CHANGES
        // Check if your at the last question so the next button will stop being displayed.

        if (questionNumber > 0 ) {
                prevbtn.style.display = 'grid'
        }else{
            prevbtn.style.display = 'none'
        }
        if (Quiz.length - 1 <= questionNumber) {
            nextbtn.style.display = 'none';
            resultbtn.style.display = 'grid';
        }else{
                nextbtn.style.display = 'grid';
        }

        // Displays Question
        questionName.textContent = question.questionDescription;
        questionName.id = "questionID";

        
    }

    function PrevQuestion(){

        questionNumber--;
        let oldAnswerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_anwser');

        // Deletes old question when the next question is clicked
        for (let answerButton of oldAnswerButton) {
           //CORRECTION DONE HERE
            answerButton.remove();
        }

        let question = Quiz[questionNumber];

        // Displays answers of the questions
        for (let y = 0; y < question.chosenAnswer.length; y++) {
            let item = question.chosenAnswer[y];
            // Display answer buttons
            let btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.value = item.id;
            btn.className = "filter_anwser";
            btn.textContent = item.name;
            button.appendChild(btn);
        }
        //FIX - FOR NEXT BUTTON AND PREVIOUS BUTTON CHANGES
        //Check if your at the last question so the prev button will stop being displayed.
        console.log(questionNumber);
        if (questionNumber < Quiz.length - 1) {
                nextbtn.style.display = 'grid';
        }
        if (questionNumber <= 0) {
            prevbtn.style.display = 'none';
        }else{
                prevbtn.style.display = 'grid';
        }

        // Displays Question
        questionName.textContent = question.questionDescription;
        questionName.id = "questionID";
    }
    
    function getLink(url) {
    let tmp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        // Check if question is from the same quiz part and adds a , between chosen answers and add the right prefix at the beginning
        if (url[i].length > 0){
            tmp.push("" + Quiz[i].prefix + url[i].join(","))
        }
    }
    /// If answers are from different quiz parts add a & between answers.
    console.log(url, questionNumber);
    return "" + tmp.join("&");
};

button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
            
    //FIX - CLICK HANDLING ONLY FOR YOUR answer BUTTONS
    if("filter_anwser" == e.target.className){
    //FIX -  since Counter logic was update above, hence updated condition check here too
        // clear the url array if there's nothing clicked
      if (url.length < questionNumber + 1) {
          url.push([]);
      }

      let quizUrl = url[questionNumber];

      // Check if a button is clicked. Changes color and adds value to the url array.
      if (quizUrl.indexOf(tgt.value) === -1) {
          quizUrl.push(tgt.value);
          e.target.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      // Check if a button is clicked again. If clicked again changes color back and deletes value in the url array.
      } else {
          quizUrl.splice(quizUrl.indexOf(tgt.value), 1);
          e.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
      console.log(getLink(url));        
    }

})
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="question"></div>
    <div id="answer"></div>
    <button onclick="NextQuestion()" id="nextbtn">Next</button>
    <!--At first there should not be a previous button Hence update this-->        
    <button onclick="PrevQuestion()" id="prevbtn">Previous</button>
    <div id="finalLink"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP asked "I'm trying not to create an entire new set of elements, but going back to the previous set." ; your approach is different and may break the quizz since you remove buttons that may possibly hold answers?

Comment: yeah that should have been my counter question - I agree.
Even in the current code shared by them doesn't have the chosen answer stored anywhere, so may be it is still a work in progress.

May be they can save the chosen answer in the object on answer button click, that's why they have something= in every array element object.

Comment: In his screenshot, some buttons have orange background so I assumed he did some selection code but didn't share it ;)

Comment: whoops. yeah it could be possible.
I only did check the code he provided, and that didn't had the selection part.
Yeah may be that part is not shared its possible.

Comment: @NikhilPandit It's after pressing previous one time it disapears and didn't save the progress so it get's redundant. Also for some reason when i press previous it edits the value of the question 2 loops further with the value on what i clicked instead of the question where i am. I do save the information somewhere I just didn't share it before but I'll add it sorry for that.

Comment: @NikhilPandit I added it!

Comment: @thijs I have edited the answer yesterday after checking few things.
Its now working as expected, do check the FIX - comments where the changes are done.

Comment: @NikhilPandit Tnx man but it still doesn't really work and it doesn't save the progress of the previous question

Comment: In what terms its not saving the progress?
I did check the console output of your array and its printing the answer correctly.
Only the orange color is not maintained for which I already mentioned the reason in my answer and how to handle it.
You have to handle that in the previous and nextButton functions that you have by accessing your url array.

Please accept the answer as it does answer your quetion and the edited sub question too.